# The number of objects selected

Tags: select

I would like to know the method which I can know the number of objects I have selected in the viewport. Precisely in object mode. Thank you in advance (:.

Comment: One way you can know is by going to the outliner.  It shows all objects and which ones are selected.  Just make sure that all hierarchy is shown when counting the selected objects.

Answer (score 13):

In Blender 2.93.0 version, you can go in the 3D Viewport to the top right under *Viewport Overlays* (icon is an open circle intersecting a closed circle) and enable the *Statistics* checkbox.

Then at the top left of the 3D Viewport you will see statistics for Objects, Vertices, Edges, Faces, and Triangles. Objects will be displayed as "number selected / total number", so if you have 95 objects and 5 are selected, you will see "Objects 5/95".

Answer (score 3):

In the Info editor, the line in the menu bar to the right of the controls lists some stats about the view. This includes a count of how many objects are selected, out of the total number of objects in the scene.

Here's a sample screen shot of this info bar:

[image: info bar]

It lists "Objects:2/4" meaning that there are 4 objects in the scene and 2 are selected.

Comment: Could you please edit your post and [upload an image to a post using the built in tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)?

Comment: Also, highlighting the area you think is important would also help.

Comment: Note that in 2.8 that bar doesn't look that way anymore (and technically doesn't exist being substituted by status bar instead)

Comment: Thanks Mr Zak; I haven't looked at 2.8 yet.

Answer (score 2):

As Blake Hodgetts mentioned, you can see the number of objects selected in the menu bar at the top of the screen, it will show the number of selected objects / total objects.

As an extra tidbit of information if you (or others) find it helpful, you can also achieve this easily in the python console:

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
print(len(context.selected_objects))
```